# BASH move files into respective directory based on part of file name

Tags: bash, ssh

I have files with similar names, but different IDs:

```
T1_6269.dwi.RAS.correct.atlas.FA.smooth2.0mm.nii.gz
T1_6270.dwi.RAS.correct.atlas.FA.smooth2.0mm.nii.gz
.
.
```

I also have folders that I need to transfer each file into based on the first 7 characters.
Example folders:

```
T1_6269
T1_6270
.
.
```

I tried using mv * and cp * but keep moving all the files into a single directory. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write `for` loop and parse file names. E.g.:

```sh
for f in *; do id=${f:0:7}; mv $f $id/; done
```